# Telegram CLI: How to mark a message as read?

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm running a little telegram bot on my Raspberry Pi

```
telegram-cli -W -s recieve.lua
```

Here a snippet of my lua file:

```
function on_msg_receive (msg)
  if msg.text == nil then
    return
  end
  if string.sub(msg.text, 0, 1) ~= "/" then
    return
  end
  mark_read(msg.from.print_name)
end
```

But the messages aren't marked as read, maybe the command isn't right?

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your bot

```
mark_read(receiver, ok_cb, true)
```

And when you wanted to disable it,just comment it :)

Comment: I don't know :-) i'm not that good at cli but it's about the msg.chat.id